# Why is there no defined constant literal for shorts

Tags: c, types, constants, short

In the list of constants:

- `'\0'` char
- `true`, `false` boolean
- `2U` unsigned / unsigned int
- `2` int
- `2L` long
- `2.0` double
- `2.0f` float
- `""` string
- `0x0` hexadecimal integer
- `02` octal integer
- `1E-8` exponential

---

I see primarily all the constants corresponding to their standard data type or interpretation value.
However I don't see a specific for (short / short integer / 2 bytes / word / int16). Is there any particular, reasonable argument for its absence ?

Comment: There's really no point for short constants in C; int is at least the same size as short. This probably should have been closed as being primarily opinion based, though.

Comment: Constant literals are being located in read-only memory in private sector of RAM, it still burdens memory. So there is a huge difference between short and int.

Comment: Side-note: In C (not C++, it's one of the discrepancies between the two), the ["`char` literal" (`'\0'`) is actually of type `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant). In C++, the number of characters changes the type; [it's `char` with a single character, or `int` (like C) with more than one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

Comment: That's what I call with no point ^ This wouldn't ruin the portability, memory though. So I truly see no point in it. Treating a char literal as int ... uh. Interpreting int with char.. uh. Sounds very unfit.

Comment: @Malina are you saying that constant literals like 2 and '\0' are stored in memory? Why would that be necessary?

Comment: @BobbySacamano Of course they are stored. It is still data. Where are stored varies from one compiler to another so I cannot tell implicitly. Besides, HDD storage still counts lol.

Comment: @Malina When I look at the assembly output of something like `int a = '\0'`, it evaluates to `mov [a], 2`. Is it defined somewhere in the standard that every literal has to exist in memory?

Comment: AFAIRC It says that they are treated just like regular variables except that their values occur only once and cannot be modified respectively. I know that the data must be created first in order to exist in memory and contain information (for instance values from constants), otherwise a plain constant wouldn't make much sense. So here is more a matter of explicit conversion. In modern compilers.. even in ancient compilers it does that instead.. to maintain memory.